# how to make a foreign keys automatically filled in a relational data connected to a c# app

Tags: c#, sql-server

i build a c# app can save data into a sql server relational database and i don't know why the foreign keys don't filled up 'they filled by None', i thought that they will filled automatically if i create the relations between the tables, i didn't create a code that save them anyway, please some one have any idea about that issue.

i tried to create a code in my c# app to fill the by taking the primary key from the first table that will saved then assign it to the foreign key but it doesn't work

```
public static bool dataInsertVisiteur(Visiteur c)
        {
            // creation d'un return default 
            bool IsSuccess = false;

            // connection avec la base de données
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(MyConnStrng);

            try
            {
                conn.Open();

                // la requête SQL pour insertion des données

                // table Visiteur
                string sql1 = "INSERT INTO Visiteur (Nom_Visiteur, Prénom_Visiteur, EmailAdresse, CellPhoneNumber) VALUES (@Nom_Visiteur, @Prénom_Visiteur, @EmailAdresse, @CellPhoneNumber)";

                // creation des commandes SQL
                SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(sql1, conn);

                // creation du parameter add data

                // parametrs table visiteur
                #region parametrs table visiteur
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nom_Visiteur", c.NomVisiteur);
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Prénom_Visiteur", c.PrénomVisiteur);
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmailAdresse", c.EmailAdresse);
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CellPhoneNumber", c.CellPhoneNumber);
                #endregion

                //ouverture de la connection avec la base de données


                #region table visiteur
                int rows1 = cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                if (rows1 > 0)
                {
                    IsSuccess = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    IsSuccess = false;
                }
                #endregion

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }

            return IsSuccess;
        }
```

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean? Did you get an error, unexpected results, undesired behaviour, an application crash, something else..?

Comment: Another hint as well: whenever I'm teaching developers, I tell them to **never** use AddWithValue on the parameters collection. The problem is that it doesn't specify the data type properly, and can lead to query plan caching problems at the DB end. Always use a method that lets you specify the data type. For example, try to create the parameter then add it to the collection.

Comment: i meant by it doesn't work that each data saved in it's field in all the tables but the foreign keys filled by Null, so should i save them manually they are already connected to each other

Comment: Where are the foreign key values being obtained from? In your code I can only see a `INSERT` so that would *imply* that the foreign key vakue is being supplied by the application; so the application is passing a `NULL`.

Comment: this code can only feed one table the other tables contains foreign keys refers to this table but in the code i didn't put an insert for the foreign keys, i just saib maybe they could filled automatically because they are connected to this table "this table has an id filled automatically in sql server"

Comment: As Greg wrote - don't use [addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)